# Implementing generic interfaces in Apple's Swift

Tags: swift, templates, generics, interface, protocols

I have a class with a property which should have as type what in other languages would be called a generic (or template) interface. When I try to mimic this behavior in Swift I cannot get protocols to work with the idea. For example:

```
protocol P {
    typealias T
    func returnT() -> T
}

class G<T>: P {
    var t: T

    init(t: T) {
        self.t = t
    }

    func returnT() -> T {
        return t
    }
}

class C {
    var p: P<Int>               // Cannot specialize non-generic type 'P'

    init(instanceOfP: P<Int>) { // Cannot specialize non-generic type 'P'
        p = instanceOfP
    }

    func usePsT() -> Int {
        return p.returnT()      // 'P' does not have a member named  'returnT'
    }
}
```

Errors from the compiler are reported as comments. It seems clear to me that such a situation should not be problematic: but since Swift's protocols cannot be generics (they use this obscure `typealias` syntax instead) `C` has no way to know that every class that implements `P` can be specialized for `Int`. Is there a Swift-y way to represent this situation correctly? Or is there any known workaround so that I don't have to force or de-generalize the class structure?

Comment: Unfortunately, at least at the moment Swift's protocol doesn't support generic type parameters. Only associated types are allowed, to make them generic. I've ever thought it is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

The generic isn't really needed in your protocol (use `Any`) - it's needed in your `class G<T>`. You could do this...

```
protocol P {
    func returnT() -> Any
}

class G<T>: P {
    var t: T

    init(t: T) {
        self.t = t
    }

    func returnT() -> Any {
        return t
    }
}

class C {
    var p: P

    init(instanceOfP: P) {
        p = instanceOfP
    }

    func usePsT() -> Any {
        return p.returnT()
    }
}

let gi = G<Int>(t: 7) // {t 7}
let ci = C(instanceOfP: gi) // {{t 7}}
ci.usePsT() // 7

let gs = G<String>(t: "Hello")
let cs = C(instanceOfP: gs)
cs.usePsT() // "Hello"
```

Comment: I actually may need to expose P and G to third parties, so I would like to preserve the whole type safety thing...

Comment: I guess I'm lacking imagination - why do you need the protocol? Why not just define `G` as having `func returnT() -> T`? The protocol would only be needed if you needed multiple independent "G-like" classes (which you don't seem to need, as G *is* generic)...

Comment: It's actually about a 2D Map implementation, that can or cannot retain information about its keys, in exchange with its performance. I want to implement both possibilities as two different implementation (excuse the redundancy) of a single Map interface, so that a third party could declare its classes (the role played by C) to have Map variables referencing a specific implementation, without the using code having to know what particular implementation that might be, since they share common Map features.

Comment: I kind of found a workaround for my own specific usage case of this type, but I am trading RAM usage for CPU time, and while it's good to me now, I can't tell if it will be later or if it would be for anyone else. And there might be other class structures that fall within this case, so it would be nice to find a consistent solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not ideal but saves me a lot of complications, still code is readable...
Instead of interfaces I use base class with open empty functions.
Like this:

```
public class CSTableControllerFilter<Row: CSTableControllerRow, Data> {
    open func filter(data: [Row]) -> [Row] { data }

    open func onReloadDone(in controller: CSTableController<Row, Data>) {}
}
```